# Two players must be in nether for spawns to happen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Hey I have a question for my Spiggot server, it seems that my pigman farm, wither skeleton farm, and magma cube farm only works when two people are in the nether, instead of only having one. I was told this might have to do with spigot but have searched for a while to no avail.
Plugins:

- CoreProtect
- dynmap
- Invsee

Any and all help would be appreciated

Also yes I looked at the article editing the bukkit.yml and spigot.yml files too.

Comment: Are you sure it's just the other person that happens to load the chunks in?

Comment: yes, I have a spawn platform directly above it I can also show with someone in nether vs only one in nether, but ty for the response I rly appreciate it :)

Comment: How many people are typically on your server?

Comment: depends on the day, on weekends usually 7-9

Comment: Hmm... Then I’m not sure